# MYSQL checks type, value of int

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MYSQL. Is there a way to check number in length/values.

[image]

Example:

No = 0,
Yes = 1.

Code checks what number has int. If int is 0, website displays "Not Following" (echo "Not Following";). If int is 1, website displays "Following".

My code so far -

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "php_user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "php_test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: How this question is related to the database?

Comment: U need to write more code

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm new to this and I don't know lot of things. Sorry if im not understanding something. But I created a table in database with int (1). I have searched the google, nothing that would help me in this case. I want to know what code should I use to check numbers.

Comment: @devpro I would like to know the code what checks int number.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. the field *Length/Value" is not the value in database, but the structure of your table. First create your table. Then add some rows inside, you will be able to check the values of the rows. The display of your website should not depend on the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code just opens a connection with the database. You need to create a sql Select statement.

From there you can assign the values to variables and then use simple if statements to evaluate the data.

This link contains a tutorial on select statements: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp